# How to prove $x^{1/n} $ is uniformly continuos in $[0, a]$ where $a$ is a positive real.

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I proved that this funcion is not Lispchitz continuos making $y = 2x$ and making $x \rightarrow 0$. But I'm stuck proving the uniformly continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fast answer is that $f(x)=x^{1/n}$ is continuous and any continuous function on a compact set is automatically uniformly continuous. However, I suspect that you haven't learned this theorem yet so let's prove it in a more constructive way.

You are right about $f(x)=x^{1/n}$ not being a Lipschitz function. Still, it is a [*Holder continuous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) function which is almost as good, i.e. we have 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \le C|x-y|^{1/n}.
$$
Can you prove that $C=1$ works?

Having shown that $f(x)$ is Holder continuous, can you conclude that it is uniformly continuous?

Comment: I did, thanks and since $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuos in $\lvert a, \infty \rvert$ then is uniformly continuos in all positive reals.